# Keep the reference of a programatically taken screenshot of current view in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdictionary

I have wrote code for taking the screenshot of the current view.Now I have to keep a reference of it,for future use.And I dont want to store the image in device album.I have to store it in dictionary as a parameter.is it possible?How to do it.Please help..

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what future use means. If you need to save it to disk, then you can use the `UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshot)` and then save it with `writeToFile(destinationPath, atomically: true)`, which wont need a dictionary as you can then load it back into an image using `imageWithContentOfFile()`

If you just need to store the `UIImage` inside a dictionary in memory for later use, then you can do this

```
let imageDictionary: [String: UIImage] = ["screenshot" : screenshot]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the image as a PNG using `UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage)`. This is a `NSData` object which you can store in a dictionary/plist or write directly into your library directory.

Comment: To be clear, the `UIImage` could be stored in a dictionary as long as you're not trying to write it to file.  You only need to convert it to an `NSData` object if you need to persist it or send it to a server somewhere.

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to hold it in memory, you need to save it in s variable with persistent scope. (That is, owned by something that sticks around.) If you have a VC (view controller) that's always around, you could add a property for your image to that VC.

Comment: You don't always have to put things at the global scope.  I don't know why the global scope and singletons is always your default go-to, Duncan...

Comment: Global scope wasn't exactly what I meant. A scope that persists. The example of a property/instance variable  of the view controller is an example of non-global but persistent scope. (Not necessarily the best choice, but an example of non-global scope nonetheless.)

Comment: That'd be a much better word choice in this answer.